# Multiplayer-Game Network Protocol

Tags: java, networking

I am responsible of the network part of a multiplayergame.
I hope anybody of you got some eperience with that.
My questions are:

1. Should I create an Object which contains all information (Coordinates, Stats, Chat) or is it better to send an own Object for each of them?
2. And how can i avoid the Object/s beeing cached at the client so i can update the Object and send it again? (i tried ObjectInputStream.reset() but it still received the same)

(Sorry for my bad english ;))

Comment: I have no experience in network gaming. But regarding question 2 i recommend a look at jgroups for the communication part. There are examples how to send message objects.  http://www.jgroups.org/

Comment: thanks :) there is no way to rate a comment or am i just blind?^^

Comment: Don't think so, but thank you anyway for thinking of it. Good luck with your game.

Comment: You could try Google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) - they are a very efficient means of structured data transfer.

Comment: Looks exactly like what i was searching for :) Thanks Why u two didn't post these as answers?

Comment: A few choices: JGroups (requires no running daemon except itself at default port 7800), Spread (requires a running daemon at port default 4803), TcpJLib (requires a running daemon at default port 80). All these can be changed in a config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.in the logic layer, you can split the objects, and in transmission layer you send what you want, of course you can combine them and send.

2.you can maintain a version for each user and the client also have the version number, when things change, update the corresponding version in the server and then send the updates to all the clients, then the client should update version. it should be a `subcribe` mode.

Answer (score 2):

1. For every time send all data is not good solution, just diff of previous values can be better. Sometimes(eg 1 time for every 10 or maybe 100 update) send all values to sync.

Comment: ok so i'll create a object that handles all data but set the values that didn't change = null?

Comment: may be do not send any message for no change

Comment: but if so i have to send each data on its own. Like Player.x, Player.y Player.z and so on. I wanted to send them bundled in Objects. So at least the Player data are one object and one for the ingame Chat. Maybe i just got u wrong.

Comment: Ok i'll just combine all of youre 3 answers :)